# SvelteKit: Implementing Basic Auth in Staging and Disabling hooks.server.ts in Production on Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, sveltekit

I'd like to execute basic authentication using SvelteKit's hooks.server.ts only in the staging environment, and prevent the hooks from running in the production environment. What approaches can be considered for this?

The deployment target is Cloudflare. Is it possible to ignore hooks.server.ts or any other files during the build process, for example?

I found a similar discussion at https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/7374, but I'm looking for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no real difference between 'staging' and 'production', both are full builds.  You can however use environment variables to achieve this. (those are often different between the two anyway)

Something like this perhaps

```js
import { SERVER } from '$env/static/private';

async function pass({ event, resolve }) {
  console.log('pass');
  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}

async function auth({ event, resolve }) {
  console.log('auth');
  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}

export const handle = SERVER == 'staging' ? auth: pass;
```